# Understanding AutoCAD plugin files by Example

Tags: autocad

I am interested in developing an AutoCAD plugin and am trying to understand the relationships between several different types of AutoCAD plugin files:

- Managed DLLs that ship with AutoCAD plugins
- [ARX files](https://fileinfo.com/extension/arx) that ship with AutoCAD plugins
- [CUIX files](https://fileinfo.com/extension/cuix) that ship with AutoCAD plugins

From what I can tell these three files are all inter-related and work together to initialize and load a plugin, I'm just not seeing the *forest through the trees* as to what information each file type contains, which files loads or depends on the others, etc.

It *sounds* like a plugin's core functionality is supposed to go inside the ARX file, and written in C++ and compiled for the native/target platform.

It also *sounds* like, at startup, AutoCAD loads its plugin DLLs, which are all managed .NET libraries (typically written in C#), and in turn they invoke their native/compiled respective ARX files. As to where the CUIX file comes into play, I still have no idea.

**Can anyone help explain the relationships & dependencies of these files, and what types of code/logic/data goes inside of them?** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Autodesk's website](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Customization/files/GUID-3FF72BD0-9863-4739-8A45-B14AF1B67B06-htm.html), an ARX file is basically a DLL but with a different extension. It is a plugin developed with the ObjectARX API. I don't really know if there is a significant distinction from a DLL, I have only ever written plugins using DLLs and loaded them using the NetLoad command.

A CUIx file is just a [user interface customisation file](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/AutoCAD-LT/files/GUID-55B0E62E-9F40-4A95-BCE6-180EB47C9DDD-htm.html). When you customise you UI elements and workspace, you can export this file to use on other PCs or as a backup for future use.

You can, however, [control the CUI programatically](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/AutoCAD-NET/files/GUID-71554E76-8FD5-4853-82CD-3587764CBCAC-htm.html) in order to provide contextual UI updates to augment the user experience of your plug-ins.